# How do I get the length of a string stored as a character

Tags: c

The following is my code for an interesting problem:

Basically I want to see if a and b both end up at 0 by the end of the function based on an input. For example, if the input is "UD", it should return true, but if the input is "LL", it should return false.

```
bool judgeCircle(char* moves) {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    char[] apples = moves;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(moves); i++)
    {
        if (apples[i] == 'U') { a++;}
        if (apples[i] == 'D') { a--;}
        if (apples[i] == 'L') { b--;}
        if (apples[i] == 'R') { b++;}     
    }

    if (a && b == 0) {return true;}
    else {return false;}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you heard of `strlen`?

Comment: I tried doing the following strlen(apples), I then proceeded to access first letter A by writing if (apples[i] == "A"), However I still get an error

Comment: `strlen` accepts `const char *` as an argument. *I tried doing the following `strlen(apples)`,* Then what did you get?? That should return 2. *I then proceeded to access first letter `A` by writing `if (apples[i] == "A")`, However I still get an error* What error did you get? By the way, `"A"` is a string in C. If you want a character, use single quotes: `'A'`. Please refer to your C manual.

Comment: duplicate is only for the first question. You shouldn't ask two questions in one. But your second is *very basic C* as well, just write `char x = apples[0];`.

Comment: @ncoder see my comment about string versus character. You're trying to compare characters to string pointers.

Comment: The code doesn't make sense. What is `moves`, where is it declared?

Comment: More over: what about using a debugger to trace through the program line by line inspecting the values of the relevant variables to learn what is *really* going on?

Comment: @ncoder please see [mcve] ... you should add one and make sure it compiles when copy&pasted.

Comment: @ncoder you have many errors in the code that are all basic C knowledge errors. Just fixing one of them won't fix your code. And it doesn't make sense for us to debug your code for you one little bug at a time. You need to go back and study your basic C. All the changes suggested so far are correct.

Comment: If defining `char* apples = "AP";` then `apples` is a pointer pointing to *read-only* memory. If you want to modify its content make `apples` an array by doing  `char[] apples = "AP";`.

Comment: The code, called with `"AP"`, gives `true` as it is presented right now. Still unclear what exactly is the problem.

Comment: Chameleon question :( @ncoder we are not here to do incremental code repairs

Comment: This question has changed too much to even make sense. I've voted to close on the basis that it's unclear what's being asked. It seems evident that the OP needs a basic C tutorial, not assistance with a single specific issue.

Answer (score 3):

This code doesn't even compile. The **main** problem is here:

```
char[] apples = moves;
```

1. This is invalid syntax. If you want to declare an array, the `[]` goes **after the identifier**, like `char apples[]`.
2. Even when corrected, a pointer (`moves`) is not a valid initializer for an array:

- When you leave out the dimension of the array in the declaration, the dimension must be deduced from the initializer. This is impossible with just a pointer, there's no size information in a pointer.
- Assigning an array is **not possible** in C.

If you really **want** to copy a string to a `char` array, you'd have to do something like this:

```
char apples[strlen(moves) + 1]; // one extra byte for terminating 0
strcpy(apples, moves);
```

This uses a *variable-length array*, which was introduced in C99, is optional in C11, but supported by **most** compilers. For alternatives, please do some research yourself.

---

Additionally, this line doesn't do what you probably **think** it does:

```
if (a && b == 0) {return true;}
```

The condition is evaluated as `a && ( b == 0 )`. If `a` is **not** 0, this is logically *true*, so the whole expression is true **exactly** when a is not 0 and b is 0. You seem to want:

```
if (a == 0 && b == 0) {return true;}
```

---

What's really ... *'surprising'* ... about the code is the fact that the array serves no purpose at all. You could just directly access the characters through `moves` without ever taking a copy:

```
bool judgeCircle(char* moves) {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    const size_t len = strlen(moves);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (moves[i] == 'U') { a++;}
        if (moves[i] == 'D') { a--;}
        if (moves[i] == 'L') { b--;}
        if (moves[i] == 'R') { b++;}     
    }

    return !a && !b;
}
```

This doesn't change anything about the semantics of the function, but just leaves out the one part that you got **completely** wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use another array and also the way you have initialized apples[] array is wrong.

Even then if you want to use another array, then you can change the apples[] declaration as follows:

```
char apples[100];
strcpy(apples, moves);
```

or else:

```
char *apples = moves;
```

Hope it will help !!